# Ubuntu One Music Sync

Tags: ubuntu-one

All my music has disappeared from the cloud. It was there a few days ago but yesterday when I clicked on the Music tab all I got was the info telling me how to sync etc.On the Files tab all the music folders are visible. I have synced all the music folders on the pc as instructed. As I am new to Ubuntu One and on the month's trial I need some help as to what to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you no longer have a music subscription. Please go to https://one.ubuntu.com/account/ and make sure you have the Music Streaming subscription.

Comment: Yes I do have a trial subscription. One thing is puzzling me re the music - How do you get the music files into the Cloud? Is it just a matter of syncing the files or do you have to upload each track one by one (not practical with a large library)

Comment: Sorted now thanks. I didn't realise how long the syncing operation would take to transfer my files. On my old pc and slow broadband it took about 20 hrs to upload 3gb!! But that's done now and all the data is there ok.

Comment: Yes, we also have a process obviously that looks are music files and extracts tag data in order to create the library view. Glad it works now, it's the coolest feature of Ubuntu One IMO.